# I can't think of how to write a thread queue for two teachers in python

Tags: python, queue, locking, mutex, python-multithreading

I was given a task: Create a project "Laboratory work", simulating the delivery of laboratory work by students.
At the beginning of the program, it is assumed that students receive laboratory assignments. Each
student does the work for a while, after which they hand over the work to the teacher. The delivery of the work takes
some time (the teacher cannot check 2 papers at the same time), after which the student either
receives a mark on the delivery, or completes the laboratory. Test the program for 20 students
and 2 teachers.
Events: student's request for the submission of work, acceptance of work for verification, submission of work, return
for revision.
I was able to do it, but the program only works with one teacher

```
import threading
import queue
import time
import random
from queue import Queue


class Student:
    def __init__(self, id) -> None:
        self.MIN_TEST_EXECUTION_TIME = 1
        self.MAX_TEST_EXECUTION_TIME = 5
        self._student_id = id
        self.test_execution_time = random.randint(
            self.MIN_TEST_EXECUTION_TIME, self.MAX_TEST_EXECUTION_TIME)
        self._test_result = False

    def get_id(self):
        return self._student_id

    def set_result(self, result: bool):
        if result == False:
            print(f"student {self.get_id()} went to retake")
            self.test_execution_time = random.randint(
                self.MIN_TEST_EXECUTION_TIME, self.MAX_TEST_EXECUTION_TIME)
            return
        self._test_result = result

    def take_test(self):
        print(f"student {self.get_id()} started doing the test")
        time.sleep(self.test_execution_time)

    def get_result(self):
        return self._test_result


class Students:
    def __init__(self):
        self._students = []

    def _append_student(self, student_id):
        self._students.append(Student(student_id))

    def create_group(self, students_amount):
        for _ in range(students_amount):
            self._append_student(f'#{_}')

    def get_group(self):
        return self._students


class Teacher:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.MIN_TEST_CHECKING_TIME = 1
        self.MAX_TEST_CHECKING_TIME = 5
        self.test_check_time = random.randint(
            self.MIN_TEST_CHECKING_TIME, self.MAX_TEST_CHECKING_TIME)

    def check_test(self, student: Student):
        print(
            f"teacher {self.name} started checking the student's work {student.get_id()}")
        time.sleep(self.test_check_time)
        print(f"teacher {self.name} checked the work {student.get_id()}")
        result = random.choice([True, False])
        student.set_result(result)


class Exam:
    def __init__(self, first_teacher: Teacher, second_teacher: Teacher, tested: Students) -> None:
        self.first_teacher = first_teacher
        self.second_teacher = second_teacher
        self.tested = tested.get_group()

    def start_test_process(self, student, teacher, lock):
        student.take_test()
        with lock:
            teacher.check_test(student)
        if student.get_result():
            print(f"student {student.get_id()} passed the test")
            self.tested.remove(student)
            return
        threading.Thread(target=self.start_test_process, args=(
            student, self.first_teacher, lock)).start()

    def run_test(self):
        lock = threading.Lock()
        threads = []
        for student in self.tested:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.start_test_process, args=(
                student, self.first_teacher, lock))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()


studs = Students()
studs.create_group(20)

tich1 = Teacher("ONE")
tich2 = Teacher("TWO")

exam = Exam(tich1, tich2, studs)
exam.run_test()
```

students should start the test at the same time, and teachers should check the tests in parallel

Accordingly, I don't really understand how to make a queue for two teachers... the logic should be as follows: the student takes the test to the first free teacher, if both are free, then to the first, if both are busy, then he waits for one of them to be released. I tried to implement something like this using queue.Queue(), but nothing came out.

Answer (score 0):

the solution turned out to be quite simple, I thought about it all night, but when I started solving the problem on a cold head, I was able to!

```
def queue(self, student, first_teacher, second_teacher, lock1, lock2):
    student.take_test()
    while True:
        if not lock1.locked():
            with lock1:
                first_teacher.check_test(student)
            if student.get_result():
                print(f"student {student.get_id()} passed the test - work checked by {first_teacher.name}")
                # self.tested.remove(student)
                return
            threading.Thread(target=self.queue, args=(
                student, self.first_teacher, self.second_teacher, lock1, lock2))
        if not lock2.locked():
            with lock2:
                second_teacher.check_test(student)
            if student.get_result():
                print(f"student {student.get_id()} passed the test - work checked by {second_teacher.name}")
                # self.tested.remove(student)
                return
            threading.Thread(target=self.queue, args=(
                student, self.first_teacher, self.second_teacher, lock1, lock2))

def run_test(self):
    lock1 = threading.Lock()
    lock2 = threading.Lock()
    threads = []
    for student in self.tested:
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.queue, args=(
            student, self.first_teacher, self.second_teacher, lock1, lock2))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```